# git log suppress refs matching specified pattern

Tags: regex, git, git-log

I regularly use the following `git-log` command:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

The command is perfect for me, with one exception. I maintain a set of `refs` in `refs/arch/` that I want to keep around ("arch" stands for "archive"), but I do not want to see them every time I look at my git log.  I don't mind them showing up if they are an ancestor of an existing `branch` or `tag`, but I really do not want to see series of commits that *would not otherwise* show up in the git log but for the fact that they are in the commit history of a given `refs/arch/*` `ref`.

For example, in the image below, the left-hand side is an illustration of what I see currently when I run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`.  As you can see, the commit referred to by `refs/arch/2` would not show up in the log if that `ref` didn't exist. (Assume there are no `refs` that are *not* shown in the left-hand side image.) Now, the right-hand side is an illustration of two alternative log graphs, either of which would be perfectly fine.  I don't mind seeing anything matching `refs/arch/*` so long as it is in the commit history of a `branch` or `tag`. But, in the image below, I definitely do not want to see the commit referred to by `refs/arch/2`.

[image: Illustration of question]

How can my `git-log` command be modified to suppress `refs/arch/*` in either of the senses depicted in the illustration?

Comment: Have you tried the same command without the `--all` option?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Yes, but without `--all` it wouldn't show `dev` or `dev~1` (if I have `master` checked out.)

Comment: Ok you're right, and what about adding the `short`param` to the `--decorate` option?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Still only going to show path from root to `HEAD`.

Comment: @derp version 1.8.3.2.  Doesn't recognize that option.

Comment: @derp If that's exactly what I'm looking for... there's a good chance!  I suspect upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to the latest non-LTS release would do it. I'll check.  If not, I'll consider whether to install a later version of git outside of the packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --exclude 'refs/arch/*' --all
```

The `--exclude` option is [new in git 1.9.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.0.txt#L156).

---

From the git-log manual page:

> `--exclude=<glob-pattern>`
>
> > Do not include refs matching *`<glob-pattern>`* that the next `--all`, `--branches`, `--tags`, `--remotes`, or `--glob` would otherwise consider. Repetitions of this option accumulate exclusion patterns up to the next `--all`, `--branches`, `--tags`, `--remotes`, or `--glob option` (other options or arguments do not clear accumlated patterns).
> >
> > The patterns given should not begin with `refs/heads`, `refs/tags`, or `refs/remotes` when applied to `--branches`, `--tags`, or `--remotes`, respectively, and they must begin with `refs/` when applied to `--glob` or `--all`. If a trailing `/*` is intended, it must be given explicitly.

---

If you are on some flavor of Ubuntu you can upgrade git from [the Ubuntu Git Maintainers team ppa](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get upgrade`